# How can I give reference of properties(connections) of persistence.xml in properties file in java

Tags: java, jpa, persistence.xml, properties-file

I have persistence.xml --------

`<persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>
        oracle.toplink.essentials.PersistenceProvider
    </provider>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="toplink.logging.level" value="INFO"/>
        <property name="toplink.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="toplink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhost:l521:MYSID"/>
        <property name="toplink.jdbc.password" value="tiger"/>
        <property name="toplink.jdbc.user" value="scott"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>`

I have to give the reference of various properties used above by using **properties file** in Java,So any have idea how to do that.????

Comment: You cannot just 'reference' the contents of a properties file in your persistence.xml, but you can for example replace placeholders on build. What build system are you using?

Comment: I am not getting what You are talking about build system .

Comment: Meaning how do you go from source code to an executable application. Popular choices are ant, maven, gradle.

Comment: As In normal Jpa working we only use persistence.xml for configuring whole connection  ,So my question is that,Cant it be done, Same in Open Jpa.....!!!!